# Stop asking for password when installing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, bundler

Whenever I bundle my rails 3.2 gems, it asks me for my password:

> Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system

This gets really annoying, especially when bundling several times in one project. However, when I set the gem directory to world-readable, it always gives me a warning when executing any (!) rails command. This is even more annoying, of course.

How can I turn this off?

Comment: What system are you running? Mac, linux, ... windows?

Comment: I've never had these problems when installing RVM as the user that I'm coding in.  They abound when you install as root (or use `sudo`).

Comment: what is the exact command and full output?

Comment: Command: `bundle`, output: `Enter your password to install the bundled ruby gems`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely has to do with the system ruby, not RVM, *unless* you installed RVM using the Multi-User installation type. If you did that and its still asking you for your password, then you installed **as root**, **strictly against what the listed documentation states**, and your general user was not added to the 'rvm' group the installer creates. (NOTE: This is based on the idea that you want a multi-user install, not a single user one. If you want the single user install, not *not* prefix with sudo when you run the installer.)

Rip out RVM, log out then back in (to ensure a completely fresh reinitialization of the environment), and then rerun the installer command **as your regular user, not as root**, prefixing with 'sudo' as the documentation instructs.

If you do *not* have RVM installed, then follow the documentation at https://rvm.io to install either as a single user install, or as a multi-user install. In this case, without RVM installed, what Billy Chan described above is your fix, though I would suggest tightening the rules a bit by figuring out which *exact* set of commands (gem bin names) you need to run on a regular basis and adding entries for those in the sudoers file (visudo).

Right now the problem reads you trying to use the system ruby which *RVM does **NOT** control (it simply allows you access to it by setting the proper GEM_PATH, RUBY_* environment variables etc), or your RVM multi-user install was done incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks! I do use RVM, but do not know anymore if I installed as root. What does that mean? How can I find out?

Comment: I'm using rbenv, and have this problem.

Answer (score 11):

```
# install gem with the specified path
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Comment: This is the only thing that could help people who are already using the correct user. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether you want to install gems under system or under your user. If under your current user, you can simply turn this message and asking off by adjusting bundler configuration.

In your project in file `.bundle/config` add line

```
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

So whole config file can look like

```
--- 
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
BUNDLE_PATH: /home/youruser/gems/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my rails installation. A quick workaround for this is to skip bundle install during project creation like so:

```
rails new webapp -B
```

And then you can do:

```
cd webapp/
mkdir -p vendor/bundle
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Hope that helps future queries.

Answer (score 0):

The best method: Use RVM. With RVM, you can just run `gem <any command>` without adding `sudo`

If you don't want to use RVM, you can still add `sudo` before the commands. And you can set to prevent `sudo` to asking password for all commands by:

```
 $ sudo EDITOR=vim visudo
 # or any editor in your system
```

Then, edit the doc by adding following line

```
 username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
 # Where username must be replaced by your real username in system
```

I know it may not be that safe, but it's convenient to use on my own machine.

You can use the above two methods all together like me.