# Install RVM properly, keeps asking for password when installing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm a fairly novice command line user and don't understand the full implications of `sudo` and have been teaching myself Ruby on Rails. I recently re-installed Ruby and Rails using RVM as I had many, many problems. I did this on a clean Mac OS X about two weeks ago.

I'm now having "Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system" whenever I run `bundle`. Have done a bit of searching and found two opposite answers to my question, one telling me to install using sudo ([Stop asking for password when installing gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330153/stop-asking-for-password-when-installing-gems)) and other not to ([Why rvm install 2.0.0 asks for sudo password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082550/why-rvm-install-2-0-0-asks-for-sudo-password)).

I have no idea what I'm doing.

Maybe it's because I'm logged in as root and I don't actually want to install it to my system? How do I then install it, but not to my system? How would I log in as any user?

None of it really makes any sense, and I'd love it if someone could save me here.

Do I uninstall RVM using `rvm implode` and start again? Will my system Ruby be OK even though I've already installed some gems using `sudo`?

---

As requested, here is my `rvm info`:

```
device-3ebf56:~ tjobbeandrews$ rvm info

    ruby-2.0.0-p247:

      system:
        uname:       "Darwin device-3ebf56 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
        system:      "osx/10.8/x86_64"
        bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)"
        zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)"

      rvm:
        version:      "rvm 1.22.14 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
        updated:      "16 days 20 hours 12 minutes 43 seconds ago"
        path:         "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm"

      ruby:
        interpreter:  "ruby"
        version:      "2.0.0p247"
        date:         "2013-06-27"
        platform:     "x86_64-darwin12.3.0"
        patchlevel:   "2013-06-27 revision 41674"
        full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]"

      homes:
        gem:          "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
        ruby:         "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"

      binaries:
        ruby:         "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby"
        irb:          "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb"
        gem:          "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem"
        rake:         "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake"

      environment:
        PATH:         "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
        GEM_HOME:     "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
        GEM_PATH:     "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global"
        MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
        IRBRC:        "/Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/.irbrc"
        RUBYOPT:      ""
        gemset:       ""
```

and my `gem env`:

```
device-3ebf56:~ tjobbeandrews$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
     - /Users/tjobbeandrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: First, do NOT run as root, and don't log in as root until you REALLY know why you should use it. Second, don't trust advice from people who didn't write RVM. Instead, follow [their installation instructions](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) and advice first. Read the entire installation page, because RVM is "full-featured", ("complicated" could be another word) and has a lot of things it can do so you want to understand it. Because you're not sure what you're doing, you should run RVM in your own home directory, not root's, and, to install and use RVM, or update gems, you'll never need "sudo".

Comment: We're going to need more information. Please run `rvm info` and `gem env` and append that information to your question by editing it and pasting the gem information in.

Comment: How do I know I've logged in as root?

Comment: Because you typed in `root` as the userid instead of your own id? Because your home directory is `/root`?

Comment: I've only ever had one log in to my MacBook Air. I've just followed the instructions on here http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528 and I now have my name, which is as admin, AND a new one, which is root.

Is it an idea for me to try and uninstall rvm and start again? Should I be logged in as admin or root when removing it, or both?

Comment: I have used Macs for years, and only use a single login. I have no need to have a separate root, as `sudo` suffices. *IF* I need to do something as root for a long period, I use `sudo su -` which switches me to the root privileges, without needing a "root" user login account, all I need is "sudo" capability. I recommend you disable the "root" account you created until you know why you need it. I'll add an answer for how to fix the RVM problem.

Comment: Thank you, you're most kind! Have disabled root access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like your RVM and Rubygems environments are set up OK. The problem is most likely that you installed something using `sudo` at some point, which now has left traces of itself in your RVM installation.

To fix this is pretty easy and shouldn't affect anything else on your machine. Run this from the command-line:

```
sudo chown -R tjobbeandrews:staff ~/.rvm
```

Here's what it does:

- `sudo` escalates your privileges to "root", allowing you to change things currently owned by "root".
- `chown -R tjobbeandrews:staff ~/.rvm` tells the system to change ownership and group of all files in the ~/.rvm directory, which is where RVM stores everything, back to you and what should be your default group.

Be VERY careful following instructions you find on the internet, especially when they ask you to do anything as "root" or using `sudo`. Making changes as root can crash your system in a second, can open the door for infections/viruses, or cause lasting problems that make your life miserable simply because the author wrote it years ago and things have changed since then.

"The internet never forgets" is true, and it's a vast garbage-pit of knowledge that can go stale within days. It's up to you to educate yourself about what is safe, and how to safely install things, and, even more important, know how to recover from the changes you do based on someone else's say-so, so walk carefully padawan.

Comment: Thank you master; I will heed your warning and follow your instructions once I am confident they aren't going to wipe my machine.

Comment: It's truly a painful learning process. Even after we've been administering our systems for years we make mistakes. I once changed the ownership of all files on our biggest HP Unix system by adding a single extra space to a path name. I freaked, and our system administrator thought it was hilarious, and had it fixed in a minute. You'll get there. :-)

Comment: thank you, lots of irony as these instructions use sudo and are on the internets :)

Comment: I tried this and it worked for the most part. I still need to sudo to install compass, I did a sudo uninstall and tried to install without sudo and got this error message`Error installing compass:
 invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `path2class' for #<Psych::ClassLoader:0x00000101a39cb8> (NoMethodError) in /Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/compass-0.12.2.gem`

Comment: I suspect there's a problem with the gem, that it's trying to write something somewhere that it shouldn't. ANY time you have to use `sudo` the code is requesting escalated privileges to do something that you, by yourself, can't do. Think about that situation; *WHY* would they need to do that?

Comment: @PeterP., there'd be irony *if* I said to use a `sudo` command and didn't explain what it does very clearly and openly. It'd be even more so if the command was embedded deeply in some code.

Comment: @theTinMan this is something new. I installed a gem with sudo by accident and now I can't install any gem without sudo. I ran your command and it installed sass without sudo. I restarted my computer to make sure things are working and it's giving that error: `invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `path2class' for #<Psych::ClassLoader:0x00000104b20f20> (NoMethodError) in /Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/sass-3.2.14.gem`

Comment: Now I can't install any gems without sudo. I just keep getting this error:`Error installing jekyll:
 invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `path2class' for #<Psych::ClassLoader:0x000001070b6780> (NoMethodError) in /Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/liquid-2.5.5.gem`

Comment: is it because I'm using a global gemset?

Comment: It sounds like your RVM environment is really confused. I'd recommend asking on the [RVM IRC channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm). They'll be able to get it straightened out.

Comment: @tinman, that's what I though did a rvm get stable, upgraded to 2.1.1 ran `sudo chown -R username:group ~/.rvm` and `sudo chown -R username:group ~/.gem` and it's installing gems as it should, without sudo. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I checked it out in both iterm and regular terminal and works great. I will never sudo another gem unless it explicitly says so. lol wow what a headache

Comment: Good to hear. Yes, we learn about `sudo` the hard way. A friend did it by accidentally `rm`ing most of a system. I did it by accidentally running `chown -r` against `/`. You got off easy.

Comment: @tinman I was ready to start wiping the system clean, can't stand when things don't work the way they should work

Answer (score 2):

You are being asked for your password because the directory which is holding your gems is owned by root.

Find the folder listed as GEM PATHS when you enter

```
    gem environment
```

in the console, then do chown -R to that folder making them owned by your user and group.  That should stop the password prompts from coming up each time.

Comment: Be VERY careful doing this as the gems can be owned by root legitimately, and are probably in the system, not the user's directory. Changing ownership of Ruby files that are *supposed* to be owned by root, which they can be on Mac OS, is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly safe to log out as root, log in as a regular user and reinstall.  RVM is environment specific.  Just make sure that the global bashrc (or bash_profile) doesn't have the rvm lines in it, it should only be in your standard users bash files to set up your env.

Comment: I've just asked this on another reply but how do I know I've logged in as root and how do I set up another account?

Comment: the command `whoami` will tell you who you're logged in as.  Adding a new user depends on what kind of system you're on.

Comment: I'm logged in as my name, doesn't say whether I'm an admin or root.

Followed the instructions on http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528 and I now have an admin and a root account, so that's something!

Comment: if `ls -al ~/.rvm` shows a file list with something other than tjobbeandrews and staff next to each file, it means that somehow you've changed permissions on your home directory rvm and you should follow tin mans answer.